# How to express the tail bound of this series as a function of $N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I encountered a problem which asks to show how the tail bound of a series converges to zero, where the tail bound has to be expressed as a function of $N$. For example, given the series:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}
$$

I can derive an estimate for its tail bound from $N$ to $\infty$ as:

$$
\sum_{k\geq N}\frac{1}{2^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k} - \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{2^k}
$$

or that:

$$
\sum_{k\geq N}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{1-(1/2)} - \frac{1-(1/2)^N}{1-(1/2)} = \frac{1}{2^{N-1}}
$$
Since $\frac{1}{2^{N-1}} \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow 0$, the tail bound converges to zero.

In the problem, I would have to derive a similar tail bound for the series:

$$
\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}
$$

If I use a similar technique as above, I would get:

$$
\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} - \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{k^2}
$$

From Euler, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, which means that:

$$
\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{k^2}
$$

Since, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, I am sure that the series converges, which implies that the tail bound $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$ should approach $0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$, however, I could not think of a way to express this decreasing tail bound sum as a function of $N$ ...

Any help ?

Comment: You can use the monotonicity of $x\mapsto \frac 1{x^2}$ and integrals to derive an estimate of the tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to show this using various series convergence tests.

Imo the simplest bound would be to use an integral:

$$\sum_{k\ge N}\frac1{k^2}\le\frac1{N^2}+\int_N^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2}=\frac1{N^2}+\frac1N$$

[Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) may also be applied to give a series you already know, using $2^n\le N$:

$$\sum_{k\ge N}\frac1{k^2}\le\sum_{k\ge2^n}\frac1{k^2}\le\sum_{k\ge n}\frac{2^k}{(2^k)^2}=\sum_{k\ge n}\frac1{2^k}$$

Another standard approach would be to use telescoping series:

$$\sum_{k\ge N}\frac1{k^2}\le\sum_{k\ge N}\frac1{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k\ge N}\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1 k\right)=\frac1{N-1}$$

Comment: thanks, for the telescoping series, may I ask how the last equality for $1/(N-1)$ was derived ?

Comment: Since the series telescopes, we have$$\sum_{N\le k\le M}\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)=\frac1{N-1}-\frac1M$$